# Manually create NPSP affiliations in Apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, npsp

I want to manually create NPSP affiliations between contacts and organisations (Accounts). Because i have a form which allows to create multiple Contacts for an Account, but this contact can represent the same person with different roles in that Organisation, so i am trying to create a trigger to check for duplicates, mark them to delete later and create affiliations with different roles/titles instead for the same account.
Here is a part of the code which i use to create Affiliations :

```
for(Contact ct : ctsList){
if(ct.Primary_contact_from_formstack__c != 'Primary'){  // AddError and Create Affiliations instead
    System.debug('Duplicate Contact : '+ct.Id+' - '+ct.FirstName+' '+ct.LastName+' '+ct.Role__c);
    ct.adderror('Duplicate Contact, an affiliation will be created instead !');
    npe5__Affiliation__c newAff = new npe5__Affiliation__c(
        npe5__Contact__c=ct.Id,
        npe5__Organization__c=ct.AccountId,
        Board_of_director__c=ct.Boards_of_directors__c,
        Member_of_Advisory_board__c=ct.Members_of_the_advisory_board__c,
        npe5__Primary__c=false,
        npe5__Role__c=ct.Role__c,
        npe5__Status__c='Current');
    
    affsToCreate.add(newAff);
}
}
    if(affs.size()>0){
        System.debug('Creating Affiliations');
        Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(affs);
        for(Database.SaveResult oneRes : results){
            System.debug('Aff -> '+oneRes);
        }
    }
    else
        System.debug('No Affiliations to insert');
```

And in the debug log i see that the Affiliations are created :
[image]

But i don't find them when i check the affiliations related list on the Account record or even when i query them using SOQL with their Ids.

NB : When i create one contact from the UI, an affiliation is created automatically but not when i create a contact from Apex.

Please tell me if i'm missing something or i am doing it wrong.

Thank you,
Best regards.

Comment: Are you performing a rollback, or is an exception being thrown, further down in the logs of this transaction?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm not rolling back and no error is thrown, that's why i'm confused.

Comment: You say :"mark the contacts to delete later" -- if you delete them, then the affiliations will be deleted also.

Comment: The contacts to be deleted are the duplicated ones, but i keep the primary contact and create affiliations only for it.